# Problema con este código en Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, kotlin

```
    package com.example.myapplication

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.text.Editable
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main3.*

    enum class ProviderType{
        BASIC
    }




class Homeactivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3)
        val bundle =intent.extras
        bundle?.getString("email")
        bundle?.getString("provider")

        setup(email?: "", provider?: "")
    }
    private fun setup(email:String, provider: String){
        title ="Inicio"
        emailTextEdit.text = email
        providerTextEdit.text = provider
    }
}
```

Esta es la segunda `Activity`, y me está dando un problema de `required Editable!`, he probado a utliizar `.setTex(provider)` o con email pero también, email y provider influyen con `setup(email?: "", provider?: "")` ya que si cambio provider e email a setText me da otro error con email y provider en la parte de setup, necesito ayuda, ya que es algo que no entiendo y que llevo buscando horas

Comment: para cambiar texto string es setText(string) nada mas.

Answer (score 0):

No debes definir el texto de esta forma   `emailTextEdit.text = email` por esa razón se provoca el error:

> Required Editable! found String? error

, debes usar el método [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/widget/TextView#setText(kotlin.CharSequence)) de esta forma:

```
 emailTextEdit?.setText(email)
```

---

Tienes otro detalle al obtener los valores del bundle, esta es la forma como debes recibir los valores y asignarlos al método:

```
var bundle :Bundle ?=intent.extras
var email = bundle!!.getString("email") 
var provider= bundle!!.getString("provider") 

setup(email?: "", provider?: "")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, que buena comunidad!

Comment: Igualmente, cuando utilizo tu método me sigue dando un error de Unresolved reference: email, en la línea de código siguiente { setup(email?: "", provider?: "")}

Comment: Ese es un error diferente, no estas asignando los valores a variables para usarlos en tu método setup() , revisa la actualización de la respuesta. @SershRX

Comment: No sabes como te lo agradezco de verdad, es un placer tener a personas como tú en esta comunidad, muchísimas gracias!